# Multiple-column list-view's issue in android

Tags: android, listview, xml-parsing

can any one tell me whats the below logcat is saying?

Actually i am trying to show the data from XML file in to a multiple column listview in android,but i am getting this issue on my log-cat?

How to overcome this?

**LOGCAT**

```
09-07 11:22:17.242: D/AndroidRuntime(796): Shutting down VM
09-07 11:22:17.242: W/dalvikvm(796): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.bindView(SimpleAdapter.java:155)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:126)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)   
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-07 11:22:17.252: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
09-07 11:22:17.322: D/dalvikvm(796): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3352 objects / 244160 bytes in 58ms
```

Thanks for you time!..